# iOS - Dispatch Async with AFNetworking on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, afnetworking, dispatch-async

Is it at all needed to wrap an AFNetworking call in a `dispatch_async`? I'm doing a simple POST to a server when the app becomes active, and I want to ensure the call is completely async and app is not waiting on resume. See below for my current code. Any problems with this approach?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] POST:@"URL" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        } 
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: So there is no performance benefit (in fact probably a performance hit) in wrapping in dispatch_async?

Comment: There is no performance benefit for sure, but I wouldn't worry about the performance hit either. I would worry about the readability of the code because of the redundancy. It is simply not needed, as AFHTTPClient take care of running the request on the background thread.